# Telegraf filecount values not showing up in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

Telegraf 1.9.0, Influxdb 1.7.4. I'm using the filecount input plugin to count the number of files in two directories. Here's the relevant test output of telegraf:

```
    $ telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --test
    2019-04-08T19:41:42Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.9.0
    > filecount,directory=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_logical/snapshots,host=db02 count=113i 1554752503000000000
    > filecount,directory=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_xlog,host=db02 count=569i 1554752503000000000
```

When I go to look up the values in influxdb using Chronograf, there is no entry for filecount at all. How can I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, in my case telegraf service had not enough permissions to scan specified directory. You can check permissions using command

```
namei -l /var/www/your/path/
```

in Ubuntu, it will show permissions for all tree, and telegraf service need to have `rx` permissions on every step of this tree. Add permissions with a group, or just

```
sudo chmod -R o+rx /var/www/
```

It's misleading that we see entries in `--test`. We start `telegraf --test` with a powerful user like `root`, but when we do `service telegraf start`, it uses it's own powerless user, this is why the difference. Gave permissions and it started working.